# Cannot Deserialize json string as i get an error

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following code

```
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(serviceurl);
List<Player> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Player>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(downloadString, typeof(List<Player>));
```

When debugging the code `downloadString` has the following value

```
"{\"GetPlayerInfoResult\":\"[{\\\"PlayerId\\\":1,\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Ryan\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Richard\\\",\\\"Age\\\":30},{\\\"PlayerId\\\":2,\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Petrus\\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Prinsloo\\\",\\\"Age\\\":20}]\"}"
```

On the desierialize line i get the following error

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WFAPlayers.Player]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'GetPlayerInfoResult', line 1, position 23."}

Any Idea how i can get around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Could be two ways to handle this kind of JSON Strings. The issue with the JSON string is that it looks like this

```
{
    "GetPlayerInfoResult": "[{\"PlayerId\":1,\"FirstName\":\"Ryan\",\"LastName\":\"Richard\",\"Age\":30},{\"PlayerId\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Petrus\",\"LastName\":\"Prinsloo\",\"Age\":20}]"
}
```

Whereas it should look like

```
{
    "GetPlayerInfoResult": [
        {
            "PlayerId": 1,
            "FirstName": "Ryan",
            "LastName": "Richard",
            "Age": 30
        },
        {
            "PlayerId": 2,
            "FirstName": "Petrus",
            "LastName": "Prinsloo",
            "Age": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

So this seems it is taking the `GetPlayerInfoResult` as a string so we can rectify the JSON string correct and deseralize it like

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText(YourJSONFile);
//remove the \ forward slash from the string 
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\\", "");
//replace the "[ to [
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\"[", "[");
//replace the ]" to ]
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("]\"", "]");
//now deseralize it normally like any other JSON String
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetPlayerInfo>(jsonstr);
```

The class structure would look like this

```
public class GetPlayerInfoResult
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class GetPlayerInfo
{
    public List<GetPlayerInfoResult> GetPlayerInfoResult { get; set; }
}
```

### Preferred / Recommended way

We can also go for double deseralization. Where we should not be changing anything in the JSON String no replacement nothing and leave it intact.

```
public class GetPlayerInfo
{
    public string GetPlayerInfoResult { get; set; }
}
public class GetPlayerInfo
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And Deserialization would be like

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetPlayerInfo>(jsonstr);
var ser1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PlayerInfoResult>>(ser.GetPlayerInfoResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Your recommended way worked really well. Mohit any chance you can help me with another problem i am having regarding another question

Comment: Sure y not!! Just paste the link of another question I would love to answer it if possible

Comment: And another way of saying thanks in here is by Upvoting the answer.

Comment: I try but i dont have the rights to upvote. I presume the upvote is when you click the up arrow.

Comment: Yeah!! @RyanRichard you are correct. Clicking the uparrow will upvote. No worries soon you will get the upvote privilege. :)

Comment: Mohit the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502317/solid-principles-refractor

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use this

```
 List<Player> myDeserializedObjList =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IEnumerable<Player>>(downloadString).ToList();
```

Some people have found that using `IEnumerable` as the type for the deserialisation can help. Alternatively you can try and deserialise straight into the list like this

```
 List<Player> myDeserializedObjList =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Player>>(downloadString);
```

EDIT:

Having a look at the string it seems that you have a container object around the JSON array so you would need one that the data can be deserialised into.

```
public class Data
{
     public List<PLayer> GetPlayerInfoResult { get; set; }
}
```

then you would call

```
 List<Player> myDeserializedObjList =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Data>(downloadString).GetPlayerInfoResult;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this and get the same error.

Comment: Pikington. Thanks for the answer. I now get the following error {"Error converting value \"[{\"PlayerId\":1,\"FirstName\":\"Ryan\",\"LastName\":\"Richard\",\"Age\":30},{\"PlayerId\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Petrus\",\"LastName\":\"Prinsloo\",\"Age\":20}]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WFAPlayers.Player]'. Path 'GetPlayerInfoResult', line 1, position 181."}